# Maximizing a Trigonometric Function of Many Variables in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, trigonometry, maximize

Just to give some context, my motivation for this programming question is to understand the derivation of the CSHS inequality and basically entails maximizing the following function:

Abs[c1 Cos[2(a1-b1)]+ c2 Cos[2(a1-b2)] + c3 Cos[2(a2-b1)] + c4 Cos[2(a2-b2)]]

where a1,b1,b2,and a2 are arbitrary angles and c1,c2,c3,c4 = +/- 1 ONLY. I want to be able to determine the maximum value of this function along with the combination of angles that lead to this maximum

Eventually, I also want to repeat the calculation for a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3 (which will have a total of nine cosine terms)

When I tried putting the following code in Mathematica, it simply spat the input back at me and did not perform any computation, can someone help me out? (note my code didn't include the c1,c2,c3,c4 parameters, I wasn't quite sure how to incorporate them)

```
Maximize[{Abs[Cos[2 (a1 - b1)] - Cos[2 (a1 - b2)] + Cos[2 (a2 - b1)] + 
Cos[2 (a2 - b2)]], 0 <= a1 <= 2 \[Pi] , 0 <= b1 <= 2 \[Pi], 0 <= a2 <= 2 \[Pi], 0 <= b2   <= 2 \[Pi]}, {a1, b2, a2, b1}]
```

Comment: Just a guess, have you tried it without Abs?
Also, asking this question on mathematica.stackexchange.com would be a good idea as well.

Comment: I moved the question over to that site, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 4.  This is because each `Cos` can be made to equal 1.  You have 4 variables a1, a2, b1 and b2, and four cosines, so there are going to be several ways of making the combinations `2(a1-b1)`, `2(a1-b2)`, `2(a2-b1)` and `2(a2-b2)` equal 0 (hence choosing the corresponding c1/c2/c3/c4 to be +1), or equal to pi (hence choosing the corresponding c1/c2/c3/c4  to be -1).

For one set of angles that give the max, the obvious answer is a1=a2=b1=b2=0.  For the 9 cosine case, the max will be 9, and one possible answer is a1=a2=a3=b1=b2=b3=0.

Regarding using Mathematica, I think the lesson is that it's always best to think about before the maths itself before using tools to help with the maths.